# Within group correlation of pearson's residuals

Tags: r, correlation, intraclass-correlation, generalized-estimating-equations, dyadic-data

I have social network data in which an "ego" names a friend "alter". I am running a regression in R in which attributes of alter are predictors of outcomes for ego. So each observation is dyadic with variable measures for both ego and alter.

There are multiple observations for each ego which are accounted for by using a gee model, clustering on ego. The problem is that i have been asked to also account for multiple observations of alter, or least to demonstrate that interdependence among the multiple alters is not impacting the final results. There are multiples of the same alter in the dataset as well as multiples of the same ego.

The two options seem to be some kind of cross clustering and I am not sure if that is possible in R. Another option which was suggested was to run a within-group correlation of some sort on the pearson's residuals, with the groups being the alters for each observation.  I had considered some sort of ICC but the number of times any individual alter shows up in the dataset ranges from 1-7. As far as I can tell, ICCs expect that the number of measures for each group in the dataset be the same.

Does anyone know how to do a within group correlation which can handle groups within which there are differing numbers of measures? I have looked online and have not come across anything that seems to address this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I thought there would be good R packages for dyadic data, but CRAN search only produced this: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dyad/index.html, which seems to offer a rather limited functionality.